# JAX-WS: How to handle exceptions when client aborted

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jax-ws

JAX-WS: How to handle exceptions when client aborted

Hi. 
Could you please tell me how to handle exceptions in JAX-WS?

The following exception was occured when the client closed connection suddenly.
I'd like to log the exceptions. How can I catch the exception?

I tried the following methods, but I could not catch the exception.

- Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()
- Servlet's request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception") and web.xml's error-page
- Filter.doFilter()

Regards,

```
2012/01/30 14:06:42 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate doGet
: caught throwable
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:112)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:284)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:339)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:481)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:160)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:75)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:313)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamWriterUtil.getOutputStream(XMLStreamWriterUtil.java:97)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:319)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:109)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:101)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:99)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:311)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:216)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:460)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:119)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:781)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:331)
    ... 36 more
```